# What are the differences in Window Service "Startup types"

Tags: .net, windows, service

What are the differences between Automatic, Manual, and Manual(Trigger Start)?
When will a service that is "automatic" actually run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic starts when the system starts, Manual means it must be started manually, and Triggered start means there's an event that starts/stops the service

Watch here for more: https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/philpenn/Trigger-Started-Services